# FFMPEG stuck on a single frame with speed less than 1x

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

When i run the FFMPEG file, the speed is 1.5x and as it runs it becomes 1.4x,1.3x and so on. After a while when it goes below 1x, the frame is kind of stuck and it does not exit out. Any help is truly appreciated
This is my FFMPEG file

```
ffmpeg -xerror -loglevel error -stimeout 1111111 -rtsp_transport tcp -v verbose -i "rtsp://admin:admin1234@10.8.0.14:81/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1 "  -vf scale=352:288 -vcodec libx264  -sc_threshold 0 -f hls    -hls_flags delete_segments    -hls_time 2  -segment_time 2 -hls_list_size 2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\ipcam\video_1\stream.m3u8
```

Comment: Is there any subtitle in the stream?

Comment: @thekamilz Hey,  there is no subtitle.